# Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-D3gXe4ZIgM9g1W3O/udv/J6fM4Hbmg0MX9V3V69QO9s='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable

Tags: angular, security, inline, content-security-policy

I tried CSP on my Angular HTML code

This is the code

```
<meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ 'nonce-2726c7f26c'; img-src 'self' data:; connect-src 'self' http://localhost:3000"
    />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      nonce="2726c7f26c"
    />
```

But I'm getting this error everytime

```
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-D3gXe4ZIgM9g1W3O/udv/J6fM4Hbmg0MX9V3V69QO9s='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Any help?